# Dictionary with byte array argument

Tags: c++-cli

I have a dictionary myResult:

```
Dictionary<String^,array< Byte >^>^ myResult = gcnew Dictionary<String^,array< Byte >^>();
```

I am declaring

```
array <Byte^>^ a;
```

and then I am adding a to a key of the dictionary

```
myResult->Add("OVERVIEW",a);
```

I am getting an error

```
error C2664: 'System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<TKey,TValue>::Add' : 
cannot       convert parameter 2 from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'cli::array<Type> ^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TKey=System::String ^,
1>              TValue=cli::array<unsigned char> ^
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              Type=System::Byte ^
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              Type=unsigned char
1>          ]
```

Any help is appreciated since I am still not very familiar with c++/cli;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dictionary<String^,array< Byte >^>^
                          ^ Uppercase B

array <byte^>^ a;
       ^ Lowercase B
```

`Byte^` and `byte^` name different types (actually, I am somewhat surprised that the latter compiles, though I am not a C++/CLI expert).  The former is a tracking handle to a `System::Byte`.  The latter is an `unsigned char` (apparently the compiler is dropping the hat, I presume it does so because it is not a CLI type, making it ineligible to wear hats).

Comment: That was a typo in the question. In the code they are both capital letters. I fixed the question now. The error is there even though both have capital B in Byte.

Comment: Assuming the error is what you say it is, this is still the problem:  the types are not the same.  One is `Byte^`, the other is `unsigned char`.

Comment: Sorry I just understood what you mean. I want to store image data into the array. Which one should I be using?

Comment: Probably an `array<Byte>^` (no hat on `Byte`).

Comment: but any idea how i can store Iplimage to array<Byte>^ ?

Comment: I never saw the unedited question, but you still have a typo that explains the build error:

The second type in the Dictionary declaration is `array<Byte>^` but `a` is declared as a `array <Byte^>^`  These types should match.